# jQuery Popup submit not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have created a popup which allows users to edit a value then they can submit it again

Html:

```
<body>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" data-theme="b" data-icon="check" data-rel="popup"/>
<div id="success" data-role="popup">
</div>
<div id="fail" data-role="popup">
    <p>Fail</p>
</div>
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var doStuff = true;
    if(doStuff === true){
        $("#success").empty();
        $("#success").append('<p> <input type="text" value="' + doStuff + '" /> <input type="submit" id="popupConfirm" value="Submit" /> </p>');
        $("#success").popup("open");
    }else{
        $("#fail").popup("open");
    }
});

$('#popupConfirm').click(function(){
    console.log("jhasgd");
});
```

Currently the click is not working at all that's why I have gibberish in the `console.log` and also I am not sure how to get the value of the entered input.

So my question is first how can I get the submit click to work and then output what they wrote?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d94nX/) of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '#popupConfirm', function(){
    console.log("jhasgd");
});
```

Comment: Ok i went straight to the answer. The listener was added before the dom element was appended. Now you delegate the event on the document, which exists at the moment. You should dleegate to a parent element that is not changing tho like $('#success').on('click','#popupConfirm', function() { } );

Answer (score 0):

Where are you adding the jQuery code at? If you are adding it all above the HTML, it might be trying to bind the #submit input before it exists in the DOM. Can you try to wrap the code in a document ready so it won't do the click binding before the DOM gets filled up.

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        console.log("clicked the button");
    });
});
```

Edit: I just saw the comment where you figured this out above. You didn't really have a code solution provided, so I will just leave this as is.